# ListView not updating upon database insertion

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, android-sqlite

I have a ListView in my app that I would like to update as I add new objects into the Database. I have looked through several StackOverflow answers but have no luck whatsoever. Here is my ListView layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/course_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/course_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/course_credits"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my custom adapter class:

```
public class CourseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Course> courses;
    private Context context;

    public CourseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Course> courses){
        this.context = context;
        this.courses = courses;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return courses.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return courses.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.courses_listview, null);
        TextView t1 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.course_name);
        TextView t2 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.course_id);
        TextView t3 = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.course_credits);

        Course course = courses.get(position);
        t1.setText(course.getCourseName());
        t2.setText(course.getCourseId());
        t3.setText(Double.toString(course.getCredits()));
        return convertView;
    }

    public void updateList(ArrayList<Course> newCourses) {
        courses.clear();
        courses.addAll(newCourses);
        System.out.println(newCourses.size());
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

and the Course class:

```
public class Course implements Serializable {
    private String courseName, courseId, teacher, location;
    private double credits;

    public Course(){

    }

    public Course(String courseName, String courseID, double credits, String teacher, String location){
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.courseId = courseID;
        this.credits = credits;
        this.teacher = teacher;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getCourseName(){
        return courseName;
    }

    public String getCourseId(){
        return courseId;
    }

    public double getCredits(){
        return credits;
    }
}
```

These are the backbone of the listview. Here is now the CoursesActivity class:

```
public class CoursesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    private static final int LAUNCH_ADD_COURSE = 1;
    private Dialog addSemesterDialog;
    private ArrayList<Semester> semesters;
    private ArrayList<Course> listViewArrayList;
    private ListView listView;
    private Spinner spinner;
    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private CourseAdapter adapter;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_courses);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.course_list);
        View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_courses, null);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                launchCourseAdd();
            }
        });

        Semester semester = semesters.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        listViewArrayList = databaseHelper.getCourses(semester.getName());
        adapter = new CourseAdapter(this, listViewArrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

   
    public void launchCourseAdd(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddCourseActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("semester", semesters.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()));
        startActivityForResult(intent, LAUNCH_ADD_COURSE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == LAUNCH_ADD_COURSE) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Semester semester = semesters.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
                adapter.updateList(semester.getCourses());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the DatabaseHelper class:

```
package com.example.finalproject.ui;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Build;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import com.example.finalproject.Course;
import com.example.finalproject.Semester;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gradeTrackerDB";
    private static final String TABLE_SEMESTERS = "semesters";
    private static final String SEMESTER_NAME = "SEMESTER_NAME";
    private static final String SEMESTER_START = "SEMESTER_START_DATE";
    private static final String SEMESTER_END = "SEMESTER_END_DATE";
    private static final String CURRENT_SEMESTER = "CURRENT_SEMESTER";

    private static final String TABLE_COURSES = "courses";
    private static final String COURSE_NAME = "COURSE_NAME";
    private static final String COURSE_ID = "COURSE_ID";
    private static final String COURSE_CREDITS = "COURSE_CREDITS";
    private static final String COURSE_COLOR = "COURSE_COLOR";
    private static final String INSTRUCTOR_NAME = "INSTRUCTOR_NAME";
    private static final String LOCATION = "LOCATION";
    private static final String SEMESTER = "SEMESTER";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_SEMESTERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SEMESTERS +
                "(" +
                SEMESTER_NAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," +
                SEMESTER_START + " TEXT," +
                SEMESTER_END + " TEXT," +
                CURRENT_SEMESTER + " INTEGER" +
                ")";
        String CREATE_COURSES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COURSES +
                "(" +
                COURSE_ID + " TEXT," +
                COURSE_NAME + " TEXT," +
                COURSE_CREDITS + " REAL NOT NULL," +
                COURSE_COLOR + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                SEMESTER + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
                INSTRUCTOR_NAME + " TEXT," +
                LOCATION + " TEXT," +
                " FOREIGN KEY ("+SEMESTER+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_SEMESTERS+" ("+SEMESTER_NAME+"), " +
                "PRIMARY KEY (" + COURSE_ID + ", " + COURSE_NAME + "))";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SEMESTERS_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_COURSES_TABLE);
        Date date = new Date();
        LocalDate localDate = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        int month = localDate.getMonthValue();
        int year = localDate.getYear();
        String semName="";
        String startDate;
        String endDate;
        if (month >= 1 && month <= 4) {
            semName = semName.concat("Winter ");
            startDate="01/07/"+Integer.toString(year);
            endDate="04/09/"+Integer.toString(year);
        }
        else if (month >= 5 && month <= 8) {
            semName = semName.concat("Summer ");
            startDate = "05/10/" + Integer.toString(year);
            endDate = "08/11/" + Integer.toString(year);
        }
        else {
            semName = semName.concat("Fall ");
            startDate = "09/09/" + Integer.toString(year);
            endDate = "12/08/" + Integer.toString(year);
        }
        semName = semName.concat(Integer.toString(year));
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            // The user might already exist in the database (i.e. the same user created multiple posts).
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(SEMESTER_NAME, semName);
            values.put(SEMESTER_START, startDate);
            values.put(SEMESTER_END, endDate);
            values.put(CURRENT_SEMESTER, 1);
            // Notice how we haven't specified the primary key. SQLite auto increments the primary key column.
            db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_SEMESTERS, null, values);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();

        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS semesters");
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public Semester addSemester(String name, String startDate, String endDate){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();

        try {
            // The user might already exist in the database (i.e. the same user created multiple posts).
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(SEMESTER_NAME, name);
            values.put(SEMESTER_START, startDate);
            values.put(SEMESTER_END, endDate);
            Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(startDate);
            Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(endDate);
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            Date currentDate = new Date();
            if (date1.compareTo(currentDate) <= 0 && date2.compareTo(currentDate) >= 0)
                values.put(CURRENT_SEMESTER, 1);
            else
                values.put(CURRENT_SEMESTER, 0);

            // Notice how we haven't specified the primary key. SQLite auto increments the primary key column.
            db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_SEMESTERS, null, values);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            Semester s = new Semester(name, startDate, endDate, 1);
            return s;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();

        }

    }
    public ArrayList<Semester> getSemesters(){
        ArrayList<Semester> semesters = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "select * from semesters";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        try{
            while (c1.moveToNext()){
                String semesterName = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(SEMESTER_NAME));
                String semesterStart = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(SEMESTER_START));
                String semesterEnd = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(SEMESTER_END));
                int currentSemester = c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndex(CURRENT_SEMESTER));
                Semester semester = new Semester(semesterName, semesterStart, semesterEnd, currentSemester);
                semesters.add(semester);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        finally {
            if (c1 != null && !c1.isClosed()) {
                c1.close();
            }
        }
        return semesters;
    }

    public Semester getSemester(String semName){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        Semester semester = new Semester();
        try {
            String mysql = "select * from semesters where SEMESTER_NAME=?";
            String[] args = {semName};
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(mysql, args);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                semester = new Semester(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SEMESTER_NAME)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SEMESTER_START)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SEMESTER_END)), cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CURRENT_SEMESTER)));
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            return semester;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
            return semester;

        }
    }

    public Semester updateSemester(String oldName, String newName, String startDate, String endDate) throws ParseException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Semester semester = new Semester();
        db.beginTransaction();
        Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(startDate);
        Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(endDate);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        int currentSemester = 0;
        if (date1.compareTo(currentDate) <= 0 && date2.compareTo(currentDate) >= 0)
            currentSemester = 1;
        try {
            String mysql = "UPDATE semesters SET " + SEMESTER_NAME + "=\"" + newName + "\", " + SEMESTER_START + "=\"" + startDate + "\", " + SEMESTER_END + "=\"" + endDate + "\", " + CURRENT_SEMESTER + "=" + currentSemester + " WHERE " + SEMESTER_NAME + "=\"" + oldName + "\"";
            semester = new Semester(newName, startDate, endDate, currentSemester);
            db.execSQL(mysql);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
            return semester;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Course> getCourses(String semesterName){
        ArrayList<Course> courses = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "select * from courses WHERE SEMESTER=\"" + semesterName + "\"";
        Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        try{
            while (c1.moveToNext()){
                Course course = new Course(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(COURSE_NAME)), c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(COURSE_ID)), Double.parseDouble(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(COURSE_CREDITS))), c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(INSTRUCTOR_NAME)), c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(LOCATION)));
                courses.add(course);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
        finally {
            if (c1 != null && !c1.isClosed()) {
                c1.close();
            }
        }
        return courses;
    }

    public Course addCourse(Semester semester, String courseName, String courseID, String credits, String color, String teacher, String location){
        Course course = new Course();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            // The user might already exist in the database (i.e. the same user created multiple posts).
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COURSE_NAME, courseName);
            values.put(COURSE_ID, courseID);
            values.put(COURSE_CREDITS, Double.parseDouble(credits));
            values.put(COURSE_COLOR, color);
            values.put(SEMESTER, semester.getName());
            values.put(INSTRUCTOR_NAME, teacher);
            values.put(LOCATION, location);
            db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_COURSES, null, values);
            course = new Course(courseName, courseID, Double.parseDouble(credits), teacher, location);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
            return course;
        }
    }

}
```

Lastly, here is the second activity that the data is coming from:

```
public class AddCourseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    private DatePickerDialog picker;
    private int currentColor = 0;
    private String[] colors = {"#006600", "#009933", "#0033cc", "#0099ff", "#b30000", "#cc2900", "#999900", "#cccc00", "#86b300", "#996633", "#7a7a52", "#9900ff", "#9966ff", "#cc0088", "#ff6699", "#006666", "#669999", "#333399", "#666699", "#000000"};
    private ArrayList<ImageButton> imageButtons;
    private Dialog myDialog;
    private Semester semester;
    private ArrayList<Course> courses;
    private Spinner creditSpinner;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_course);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.view_courses_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        semester = (Semester)i.getSerializableExtra("semester");
        courses = semester.getCourses();

       
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(colors[currentColor]));
        }
    }

    

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selectedSemester = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        Semester semester = databaseHelper.getSemester(selectedSemester);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

  


    public void saveCourse(View view) {
        boolean error = false;
        EditText addName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.addName);
        EditText addID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.addID);
        EditText addTeacher = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.addInstructor);
        EditText addLocation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.addLocation);
        TextView nameError = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameErrorText);
        TextView idError = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.idErrorText);

        String name = addName.getText().toString();
        String id = addID.getText().toString();
        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            nameError.setText("*Course name can not be empty");
            error = true;
        }

        if (id.isEmpty()) {
            idError.setText("*ID can not be empty");
            error = true;
        }

        ArrayList<Course> courses = semester.getCourses();
        for (int i = 0; i < courses.size(); i++){
            if (courses.get(i).getCourseName().equals(addName.getText().toString())){
                nameError.setText("*A course with that name already exists");
                error = true;
            }

            if (courses.get(i).getCourseName().equals(addName.getText().toString())){
                idError.setText("*A course with that ID already exists");
                error = true;
            }
        }


        if (!error){
            DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
            Course course = databaseHelper.addCourse(semester, name, id, creditSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString(), colors[currentColor], addTeacher.getText().toString(), addLocation.getText().toString());
            semester.addCourse(course);
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("course",course);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

I have found that the course is actually being added to the database but it just not showing up in the ListView. When I launch the activity the first time and add a course, the listview is updated upon returning to the courses activity. However, after that, if I add any number of courses, it is not refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to re-initialize your list to get the newly added courses.

> Your Code

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == LAUNCH_ADD_COURSE) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            //You are getting the exisiting spinner data and reloading it .
            Semester semester = semesters.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
            adapter.updateList(semester.getCourses());
        }
    }
}
```

> Update like this

```
 @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == LAUNCH_ADD_COURSE) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
           //Add this
           databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
           listViewArrayList = databaseHelper.getCourses(semester.getName());
           adapter = new CourseAdapter(this, listViewArrayList);
           listView.setAdapter(adapter);
           //End 

            Semester semester = semesters.get(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
            adapter.updateList(semester.getCourses());
            //Added in Edit
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

This makes sure that after successfully adding a course , you are again fetching the course results and giving them to list view.

After updating the adapter ,add this.

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: I tried updating it with your code but unfortunatelty the listview did not still update